# Filter using jQuery onChange event is filtering table head, not just the table body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I am using the following code as a filter, but everytime I look for something it goes row by row and the table head disappears. How can I make it only look for the info in the body and keep the head?

```
<script>
$('#inputFilter').change(function() {
        var that = this;
        $.each($('tr'),
        function(i, val) {
            if ($(val).text().indexOf($(that).val()) == -1) {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                },
                50,
                function() {
                    $(this).find('tr').eq(i).hide();
                });
            } else {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                },
                50,
                function() {
                    $(this).find('tr').eq(i).show();
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

`inputFilter` is the id of the input of the filter and `data_fm_op` is the id of the table.

Comment: Change your selector to only look at rows in the body: `tbody > tr`, or omit rows which contain `th's`: `tr:not(:has(th))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recomend you to use `<thead></thead>` and `<tbody></tbody>` and launch the filter on `$.each($('tbody tr')`

Answer (score 0):

can you please post your HTML code it will help you to give your answer better way

try this

```
<script>
$('#inputFilter').change(function() {
        var that = this;
        $.each($('tr'),
        function(i, val) {
            if ($(val).text().indexOf($(that).val()) == -1) {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                },
                50,
                function() {
                     if(i != 0)
                        $(this).find('tr').eq(i).show();

                });
            } else {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                },
                50,
                function() {
                    if(i != 0)
                        $(this).find('tr').eq(i).show();
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```